# Parallel tests in bash, using bash or parallel GNU

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu

I have got grunt tests, it run's in Jenkins on MAC machine and i need to parallelize  lineman grunt spe and lineman grunt spe-table after them will run distributive.

```
 lineman grunt spe
 lineman grunt spe-table
 lineman grunt distributive
```

I've tried to do

```
 lineman grunt spe >spe.out 2>spe.err &
 lineman grunt spe-table >spe-table.out 2>spe-table.err &
 lineman grunt distributive
```

It works, but when test's runs, also distributive task runs, and it's not a good decision.

As a good idea i try to run parallel GNU
like this:

```
parallel -j 2 "lineman grunt spe" "lineman grunt spe-table" 
lineman grunt dist
```

But nothing happend, just see this string in jenkins output. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `wait` command after the first two commands - this will force the shell to wait for all the background tasks to complete before continuing.

```
lineman grunt spe >spe.out 2>spe.err &
lineman grunt spe-table >spe-table.out 2>spe-table.err &
wait
lineman grunt distributive
```

In this case, the last command won't be run until both sets of tests have completed.

Answer (score 1):

```
parallel ::: "lineman grunt spe" "lineman grunt spe-table"
```

or:

```
parallel lineman grunt ::: spe spe-table
```

This is some of the simplest use of GNU Parallel, so I take it you did not follow the reader's guide in 'man parallel':

> Reader's guide
>
> Start by watching the intro videos for a quick introduction:
>          http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
>
> Then look at the EXAMPLEs after the list of OPTIONS. That will give you an idea of what GNU **parallel** is capable of.
>
> Then spend an hour walking through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). Your command line will love you for it.
>
> Finally you may want to look at the rest of this manual if you have special needs not already covered.